# returning reference to local temporary object on pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++, reference, return, compiler-warnings, clang++

Clang compiler produces warning compiling this code snippet and I can't figure out why.

```
const int* Get() {
    static const int ARRAY[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    return &ARRAY[0];
}

const int& Test() {
    const auto& p = Get();
    return (*p);
}

warning: returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address] 
    return (*p);
```

GCC shows no warnings on this code.
I can fix the snippet like this: `const auto p = Get();`
But I want to know if there is some temporary object and the problem lies deeper

Comment: @101010 "temporary object"? Perhaps you could be a bit more clear? We can definitely make references to non-const variables in the stack.

Comment: Whereas `p` is a temporary, `*p` is valid. I assume it is a false positive of Clang.

Comment: @JonathanMee: [Learn about temporaries](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was a good read now that I've gotten around to it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That warning is a false positive, since the pointee of `p` is not a temporary, despite `p` referring to one. There are more scenarios in which that warning is produced spuriously; See e.g. [Bug 21218](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21218), which uses

```
char * f() {
    typedef char* t;
    const t & r = new char[5];
    return r;
}
```

Presumably, if the return type is a reference, Clang looks for const-references (that have been bound to temporaries) in the returned expression, without considering how they're used.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Clang's warning is incorrect.

Let's step through what happens here:

1. `static const int ARRAY[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};` constructs a global array of `int`s
2. `return &ARRAY[0];` returns a pointer to the first element of the global array
3. `const auto& p = Get()` stores a reference to a pointer to the first element of a global array
4. `return (*p);` creates a reference to the lvalue of the first element of the global array

**4** is the tricky one. Clang seems to incorrectly think that `*p` is a local value, when in fact we know that it is a global.

Crucial to this proof is [the fact that `*p` returns an lvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

Comment: _"That's easy to do"_ because it says so clearly in the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't have a copy of the standard myself, and I couldn't seem to find any online information confirming that the dereference operator returned an lvalue. If you can point me to a source I'd love to include it rather than an example to prove my answer.

Comment: or 5.3.1/1 first sentence in C++14

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks I've sourced... even though it is Wikipedia ;)